# LM13700 VCA circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to build a VCA from the LM137000's datasheet.

The original circuit is with +-15V while I only have a 9V supply. I wonder how the resistor values should be changed so the OTA works with 9V (split supply)? Thank you for your help in advance!

[image: Here's the circuit]

Comment: I don't think they'll work well much below +/-15V - I looked in the data sheet and saw one reference in a diagram to it working from a 12V supply

Comment: I got it working on +/-4.5v from one 9v battery. It performed a lot better on +/-9v from two 9v batteries hooked together. Tomorrow I'll try it from my +/-12v PSU. Here's a video of it in action. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSSBjNxeYMc&list=UUYDAxzwoalN3uqmwsxcbRiA&index=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your 9V supply is actually a split supply, you will probably be fine. Use caution if you intend to make more than one of these.

As far as changes, you won't need to make many.

- Put voltage dividers on + and - pins to scale their voltage to \$\pm20mV_{max}\$. You will get a more linear response this way. If you do this, eliminate the diode bias resistor. It won't be necessary.
- The gain control is where you need to pay attention. The maximum amplifier bias current (\$I_{ABC}\$) is 2mA. It is calculated as follows: \$I_{ABC}=\dfrac{V_{control_{max}}-(-V_s+1.3V)}{R_{ABC}}\$. Keep in mind that 2mA is an absolute maximum rating. \$R_{ABC}\$ must be chosen to stay under it.
- The output current is given as \$I_{out}=\frac{17}{V}I_{ABC}(V_+-V_-)\$ Since the output is a current source, you can chose any \$R_L\$ value that will give you the output voltage you need. Regardless of your choice, I recommend using an op amp buffer instead of the Darlington pair that is built into the part.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I like the idea of the Darlingtons. The 3080 doesn't have any buffer and seems to need way more external components. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wonder why did you recommend using op amp buffer instead of the Darlingtons?

Comment: It's typically easier to control the output voltage with an op amp buffer. If your next stage wants a current source, driving it straight from the output, or using the Darlington may be better. It really depends exactly what you're trying to do with the output of the VCA.